# Writing binary data html5 FileWriter

Tags: javascript, html, image, jpeg, filewriter

I am using webgl in an application and render something to an offscreen render target (frame buffer) and then do a readPixels. After getting the pixel data I convert it to jpeg using javascript jpeg encoder available here:

[Javascript Jpeg Encoder](https://github.com/vincent-huang/javascript-jpeg-encoder)

I get raw binary jpeg data that I want to write to a local file system. Here is the code that I am using for writing:

```
root.getFile(filename, {create: true}, function(fileEntry)
{
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer)
    {
        writer.onwriteend = function(e)
        {
            System.debug("Write done");
        };
        writer.onerror = function(e)
        {
            System.error(e);
        }
        var data = new Blob(jpegData, { type: "image/jpeg" });
        writer.write(data);
        jpegData = null;
        pixels = null;
        uoozo.core.write[filename] = false;
    });
},
function(e)
{
    System.error(e);
});
```

However, I get weird results. jpegData is fine when I put it to an image element however when I create the blob e.g. jpegData is 3200 bytes in size but the Blob created is always 4818 bytes and FileWriter also returns the same position after the write operation. The jpeg created is obviously wrong and doesn't open. I don't understand how I can get the FileWriter to just write the darn binary data into the file without trying to be clever (or stupid).

Can someone please help me in this? Thank you.

Comment: what format is jpegData, an array, a string, base64?

Comment: jpegData is an array of binary data. The library can provide base64 string as well but that gives the same result. I have also tried specifying different type to blob e.g. "plain/text", "image/jpg" and even empty string. Everything gives the same result.

Comment: binary as in integers or raw string chars?

Comment: Raw string characters

Comment: ok then, it's probably a unicode problem, you'll have to turn the chars into a int array to feed to Blob. See on here for examples of dataURL to Blob for some easily adaptable code (just pickup after the base64 decoding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So even after converting to Uint8Array I still wasn't getting the result that I needed. After looking at the dataURLToBlob method it dawned on me that I was passing the array object to the Blob constructor like:

```
var blob = new Blob(jpegData_ConvertTo_Uint8Array, "image/jpeg");
```

This isn't correct and apparently in order to get the Blob to work propery I need to pass an array like:

```
var blob = new Blob([jpegData_ConvertTo_Uint8Array], "image/jpeg");
```

This worked perfectly and write my jpeg to the file with a subsequent call to the FileWriter. write(blob) function. Thanks dandavis!